# default: SSH auth method: private key default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying

Tags: vagrant

I have read [kali linux in vagrant box](https://ma.ttias.be/running-kali-linux-as-a-vagrant-box-virtual-machine/):

and I follow this document.

but when I run up vagrant:

```
$ sudo vagrant up
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/util/which.rb:37: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/delo in PATH, mode 040777
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'Sliim/kali-linux-2.0-amd64' version '2.0.1' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

there I get the Authentication failure error.

---

**EDIT-01**

When I execute the `sudo vagrant ssh`, there need password:

```
kali ldl$ sudo vagrant ssh
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/util/which.rb:37: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/delo in PATH, mode 040777
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password: 
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
```

the password is not `vagrant`, so, who can help me to know the correct password?

---

In my terminal I use ssh to connect it, there I can not ssh success too:

```
$ ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -2222
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following line to your Vagrantfile to get past the Authentication failure error message.

```
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

Perhaps the root password is **toor**. Found [here](https://github.com/Sliim/pentest-env)

Comment: Check out these [keys](https://github.com/Sliim/pentest-env/tree/master/ssh-keys). Would be very helpful if you post your Vagrantfile as well.